# Blazor get data with multiple arrays from json, api call

Tags: c#, arrays, json, blazor

I am trying to display a table of data that i get from api call inside Blazor.
Now my issue is that i cant sort the data i recive from the api.
The structure of the json return is as follows :

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
@if (food == null)
{
    <p>Loading...</p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @if (food.Data != null){
                 // cant loop this
                @foreach (var FoodData in food.Data.c)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@FoodData.a</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private Food food;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() => await GetFood();

    private async Task GetFood()
    {
        food= await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Food("apilink");
    }

    public class FoodDetails
    {
        public string a { get; set; }
        public double b { get; set; }
        public SoldProduce c { get; set; }
    }

    public class SoldProduce
    {
        public string a { get; set; }
        public int b { get; set; }
        public string c { get; set; }
    }

    private class Food
    {
        public int ErrCode { get; set; }
        public FoodDetails Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now i do get the errcode and the error is at Data which also calls this error:

**The JSON value could not be converted to System.Collections.Generic.List**

(its a lot longer but i think that's the basic point)

**Edit:**

The issue was solved thanks to @T.Trassoudaine comment, the data was not a list and then the c was a list

Comment: Is json really incapable to see where the array is ?

Comment: Well, from what I see `Data` is not a JSON list but a JSON object, therefore the error is correct when you try to convert it to a List.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine So what would be the correct way to do it ? I am new to Blazor.

Comment: First try to replace `public List<FoodDetails> Data { get; set; }` by `public FoodDetails Data { get; set; }` then in your razor part iterate over `food.Data.c`.